# How to rapidly press a button to generate sound on Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio

Here is my following code for an Xcode project. When I press "play()," a short drum sound occurs. The thing is, when I tap the custom view multiple times in succession, I want quick drum sounds to occur in succession. However, the sound occurs after the full clip (of 2 seconds) as finished, leaving lots of deadspace. I tried many different things but I can't.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tabla: TablaHead!

var tablaSoundUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "TablaSound", ofType: "mp3")!)
var tablaAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tablaAudioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: tablaSoundUrl as URL)
}

@IBAction func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .ended {
        playNoise()
    }
}

public func playNoise() {
    if (tablaAudioPlayer.isPlaying) {
        tablaAudioPlayer.stop()
        tablaAudioPlayer.play()
    } else {
        tablaAudioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var tabla: TablaHead!

var tablaSoundUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "TablaSound", ofType: "mp3")!)
var tablaAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var tapsCount = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tablaAudioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: tablaSoundUrl as URL)
}

@IBAction func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    tapsCount += 1
    if sender.state == .ended && tapsCount == 1 {
        playNoise()
    }
}

public func playNoise() {
    tapsCount -= 1
    tablaAudioPlayer.play()
    if tapsCount > 0 {
        playNoise()
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck. I think the issue is that I don't understand AVAudioPlayer completely. Thanks for trying though!